# Linux Centos 7 unable to install png and EBImage package on R

Tags: linux, centos, path, r

I am fighting to install png and EBImage R package on my linux centos 7 machine. I have always this error message:

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘png’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/rico/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so':
  libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/rico/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/png’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpX4o4D5/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried to do:

```
yum install libpng-devel
```

and it output me:

```
Package 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Any idea how to solve this issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you also have Anaconda installed on your machine?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I have Anaconda 3 installed. Finally, I managed to install EBImage on my Linux centos  7 machine. `sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16 /usr/lib`

Comment: I had the same issue.  Once I removed anaconda from the path it was able to install the `png` package with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install EBImage on my Linux centos 7 machine. `sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16 /usr/lib` resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your R package needs `libpng16.so.16` (1.6. branch) whereas the default on CentOS 7 is the one you installed (1.5 branch, available via `libpng` package).

If you don't mind using a *commercial* repository, libpng 1.6 is available at [GetPageSpeed repo](https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/libpng16.html):

```
sudo yum -y install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-latest.rpm
sudo yum install libpng16
```

Alternatively, although highly discouraged due to placing non-packaged files on the root filesystem, you can use precompiled binaries of libpng16 located [here](http://slackware.osuosl.org/slackware64-current/slackware64/l/libpng-1.6.37-x86_64-1.txz): extract the archive, create symlink from the precompiled library file over to `libpng16.so.16`, provide custom include path from the archive to the `R` package installation, etc...

Comment: Hi Danila, thank you very for your help. I gonna use precompiled binaries of libpng16. Can you tell me how do you create a symlink from the precompiled library file over to libpng16.so.16? I gotta to search how to provide a custom include path to R package installation. That's a liltle bit new for me.

Comment: `cd /path/where/it/is/extracted && ln -s libpng16.so.16.37.0 libpng16.so.16` that would be a mere equivalent of what a libpng16-devel package would install (unversioned soname file).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason having Anaconda on RHEL/Centos 7 causes this issue.  Probably because Anaconda installs a more recent version of `libpng`.

I was able to get another package installed that had the same `png` package dependency by temporarily removing anaconda from the `PATH` recognized by R. Once I did this, the `png` package and its dependent package installed with no issues.